# C# Auto Increment Primary Key with String?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, primary-key, auto-increment

I am newbie to C# and programming...

When form loading primary key has to load automatically to comboBox and it has to automatically generate +1 from last value.. for example if `COUNT` value is 0 then it has to add like this `EMP01`

Here's my code:

```
class PrimaryKeyIncrement
{
    public void empPrimary() {
        Dbconnection ObjDb = new Dbconnection();
        ObjDb.ConnectWithDB();

        string empPri = "SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) AS PK FROM Employees";
        SqlCommand Pri = new SqlCommand(empPri, ObjDb.conct);
        SqlDataReader rd = Pri.ExecuteReader();

        if(rd.Read()){
            string pk = rd["PK"].ToString();

            int IC = Int32.Parse(pk);
            IC++;

            string empPK = ("EMP")+IC.ToString();

            EmployeesManager EM = new EmployeesManager();
            EM.cmbEmployeeID.Items.Add(empPK).ToString();

        }        
    }
```

and i called empPrimary() method in EmployeesManager Form load..
There is no errors but nothing loading in the comboBox

[image: Out put results Nothing showing in comboBox]

Please help me Primary key should increase by one with String EMP

Comment: Let your database handle assigning a PK.  It will do a better job than you can and thats part of its job,

Comment: It's not a good practice to add the primary key in code. You need to do that in Database and while displaying you have to use DataTextField & DataValueField to display.

Comment: @Plutonix yeah but it has to add EMP so i gave varchar in Database for primary key only integer can auto increment in Database right?

Comment: @Ahamed - It looks like you only need the user to see that it has "EMP", the database is much better off handling its own PK as plutonix has said

Comment: @Sayse Yeah!! but according to the scenario i have to do with "EMP" that's why i am struggling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual cause of the issue you are having is because you are adding to a **new** EmployeeManager's combobox. You need to pass a reference to your form into your `EmpPrimary`

```
... EmpPrimary(this); //in your forms form load

public void empPrimary(EmployeeManager form){ //change the method parameters

form.cmbEmployeeID.Items.Add(empPK); // Now use the form reference in method
```

As plutonix has stated however, you should let the form handle the PK's itself